# Simple way for installing multiple operational systems and boot between it?

Tags: installation, operating-systems, multi-boot

I need to install Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP and CentOS on a single computer.

I am aware of virtualization but it would be better for my situation to install each OS and just switch between them without virtualization most because of video card, memory, etc.

I know how to install Windows and Linux with Linux being the boot manager but I don't know how could I install 4 OS and have the Linux OS to manage all the boot.

If some one could explain how would I have to proceed in order to accomplish this I would appreciate very much.

For example, is it all I need to install all the Windows and the Linux as last and set it as the boot manager or am I able to install the Linux first and the other after and still maintain the Linux as the boot manager ?

Or how this process would be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im pretty sure that as long as you install CentOS last, grub will take over and will be your default boot manager.

I would start with Xp, Vista, 7, CentOS. I recommend the older versions of Windows first because the newer ones (so I've heard) like to dominate HDDs and make it harder to install another version.

Comment: thanks for the reply I am just waiting for a friend to drop by with the win7 cd to start doing the installations, I never tried installing more then 2 OS's so I was not very sure i could just install one after another and leave the linux at the end to have it working i just know that the linux is able to not only control but let u choose which one u want to be the main bootable OS.

Comment: @Guapo yeah GRUB is an amazing boot manager. Good luck with your installations.

Comment: XP>Vista>W7>Cent OS

Comment: if for some reason you want to use the windows 7 or vista bootloader, you can set it up with easybcd after installing in the order MaxMackie suggested.